# On Trello card is it possible to assign a card by email?

Tags: trello

I would like to turn an email into a card and assign it to someone in my organization on a specific Board.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Don't want to disappoint you, but supposedly no : if you want to get people’s attention, you can mention them in a comment (use @ followed by their name). It will generate a notification.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the feature request card to [Create Cards via Email](https://trello.com/card/create-cards-via-email/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1171).

Automatically assigning new cards in a list to a particular user would fall under a different feature request (Workflow) which is not on the public development board yet. Email us at `feature-ideas@trello.com` to express your support for that feature.